# XSL template match on attribute of parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML that looks like this:

```
  <section class="DoCO:Section">
    <h1 class="DoCO:SectionTitle" id="42" page="3" column="2">EXPERIMENT</h1>
    <region class="DoCO:TextChunk" id="43" page="3" column="2">lots of body<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="R7" id="35" class="deo:Reference">7</xref> text</region>
    <region class="DoCO:FigureBox" id="F4">
      <image class="DoCO:Figure" src="2cn.page_003.image_04.png" thmb="2cn.page_003.image_04-thumb.png"/>
      <caption class="deo:Caption" id="44" page="3" column="2">Figure 4: Experimental Setup</caption>
    </region>
```

I had been using the following XSL to match on the xref elements individually:

```
                <xsl:for-each select="article/body/section">
                    <sec>
                        <xsl:for-each select="h1">
                            <title>
                                <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                            </title>
                        </xsl:for-each> 

                        <xsl:for-each select="region">
                            <p>
                                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                            </p>
                        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xref">
    <xref/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I want to be able to group the image and caption elements together within a given region without changing the very open-ended way of handling region elements currently, so I'm trying to do the following:

```
<xsl:template match="@class[.='DoCO:FigureBox']">
    <fig xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <graphic>
            <xsl:for-each select="image">
                <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@src"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </graphic>
        <caption>
            <xsl:for-each select="caption">
                <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </caption>
    </fig>
</xsl:template>
```

But the match="@class[.='DoCO:FigureBox']" doesn't appear to be firing. Is it not possible to match on an attribute of the parent of xsl:apply-templates the same way you can match on a child element?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give a sample of your expected output in this case, just to make it clear what you are trying to achieve? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the following syntax:

```
<xsl:template match="@class[.='DoCO:FigureBox']">
```

Your (first) problem, lies here

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

This is a short-hand for this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
```

Which means, you are not selecting any attributes, and so your template match for the attribute **@class** will not be called.

Now, you could change it to this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
```

But this leads on to a second problem. Within the template matching **@class**, you have a couple of **xsl:for-each** statements, for **image** and **caption**. But at this point, you are positioned on the **@class** attribute, not a **region** elements, and so these **xsl:for-each** statements will find nothing.

What you probably should be doing, is that instead of doing `<xsl:for-each select="region">` in your main code, do `<xsl:apply-templates select="region" />`. Then, you can have two templates, like so

```
<xsl:template match="region">
   <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
   </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="region[@class='DoCO:FigureBox']">
    <fig xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <graphic>
            <xsl:for-each select="image">
                <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@src"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </graphic>
        <caption>
            <xsl:for-each select="caption">
                <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </caption>
    </fig>
</xsl:template>
```

The XSLT processor should give priority to the more specific template in this case, so it will override your default handling of the **region** element.

In fact, if you are always going to have one **caption** and **image** per region, you could simplify the template to this:

```
<xsl:template match="region[@class='DoCO:FigureBox']">
    <fig xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <graphic xlink:href="{@src}" />
        <caption>
            <xsl:value-of select="caption" />
        </caption>
    </fig>
</xsl:template>
```

Notice the use of Attribute Value Templates in creating the attribute. The curly braces indicate and expression to be evaluated, not output literally.